# Еще о родственных словах

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Подумалось: слова "кров", "кровля" и "кровь" родственные или нет? И, если первые два — понятно, означают "покрывать", то при чем тут кровь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Кров** и **крыть** действительно родственные слова.

Слово **КРОВ** заимствовано из ст.-сл. **кровъ**, которое восходит к праслав. *кrоvъ, которое по происхождению представляет собой звуков. видоизменение корня кры- < и.-е.* krou-/ *krau-, того же, что в слове **крыть**. В нем гласн. **ы** развился из дифтонга* 
оu (аu) *перед последующим согласн. звуком суф. -U. Ср. родственные: лит. krauti, krauji «наваливать, накладывать»; греч. krypto «покрываю, скрываю». В положении перед последующим гласн. звуком **ъ** дифтонг **оu** в слав.языках изменился в сочетание **ов**, отсюда: кровъ > кров (ср. аналог.плыть — пловец). Стар.* кров-j-а после изменения вj > вл дало сущ. *кровля* — «крыша».

Слово **КРЫТЬ** развилось из др.-рус. *крыти, крыю* — тожд.: в форме *крыти* утратился конечный безударный -и; в форме *крыю* перед j под ударением ы > о, отсюда *крою* (в укр. яз. сохранились формы крити, крию). Др.-рус. *крыти* восходит к праслав. *kryti «крыть». В нем гласн. у [ы] развился из и.-е. дифтонга ou/au перед последующим согласн. Ему родственны: лтш. krava «груз, поклажа», собств. «то, что накладывается, наваливает- 
ся»; греч. krypto «скрываю, прячу», krypte «подземный ход в скале» (ср. от греч. krypto термин криптография > криптография «способ тайного письма, тайнопись», ры> ри). Следоват., **крыть** — первонач. «накладывать», «покрывать сверху» (крышей, крышкой, навесом) > «прятать». От глаг. крыти с пом. суф. -ш-а образовано сущ.* крыша *«верхняя часть строения», устар. также «крышка». От* крыша* с уменын. суф. -ьк-а — форма 
крышка «верхняя часть сосуда, ящика и т. п.».

Что касается слова **КРОВЬ**, то соврем. форма слова является застывшим вин. п. ед. ч. *кръвь* сущ. **кры** (род. п. кръве), которое происходит из и.-е. *kreus/*krus «нечто кровавое». Ср. др.-инд. kravis «сырое мясо», kruras «кровавый, раненый». На слав. почве из дифтонга оu (еu) в одних случаях развился гласн. **ы**, отсюда им. п. **кры**, а в других случаях — сочетание ъв(ов), отсюда форма вин. п. **кръвь**, которая в рус. 
яз. после исчезновения слаб. гласн. ь и превращения сильного гласн. **ъ** в **о** приняла вид **кровь** (ср. укр. кров, но кривавий «кровавый»). Сущ. **кровь** первонач. «нечто кровавое», затем в слав. языках расширило свое знач. Оно стало называть и свернувшуюся и циркулирующую в живом организме **кровь**. Ср. в лат. яз. отмечается два слова для обозначения крови: *cruor* «запекшаяся на ране кровь» и sanguis, sanguinis «кровь, текущая в венах».

Хотя корни и похожи, но слова *кров, кровля, крыть* не являются родственными слову *кровь*, поскольку никакой семантической близости в корнях не наблюдается. По крайней мере, указания на общее происхождение нет ни в одном этимологическом словаре.

Answer (score 1):

"Хотя корни и похожи, но слова кров, кровля, крыть не являются родственными слову кровь, поскольку никакой семантической близости в корнях не наблюдается."

Мне тут всё же видится некая семантическая близость: *кровь* - это то, что должно быть *скрыто* в венах, *сокровище*. Форме *кры* соответствует глагол *крыть, скрывать*.