# Кров и кровь: однокоренные или нет?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Слова очень похожи, но значение у них совершенно разные. Являются ли однокоренными слова "кров" (убежище, жилье) и "кровь".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет: : Кровь, по Успенскому,слово индоевропейское, в
праславянском языке оно звучало так: "кры"(нечто кровавое). Родительный падеж его был
"кръве", а винительный - "кръвь". Таким образом, то, что мы сейчас считаем
именительным падежом его, является на деле переработкой древнего винительного
падежа. Слово "кровь" не единственное пережившее такую историю. То же самое
случилось со словом "бры" - "бровь", "свекры" - "свекровь", "моркы" -
"морковь" и с некоторыми другими.http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/10/str162.html

Кров, по Фасмеру, от гл. крыть из праслав. формы(скрывать, прятать) от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. крꙑти, крꙑѬ (др.-греч. κρύπτω,ἀποκρύπτω), русск. крыть, укр. кри́ти, кри́ю, белор. крыць, кры́ю, болг. кри́я «скрываю».Отсюда и  ст.-слав. кровъ, съкровиште (θησαυρός) и др. Некоторые учёные считают, что в руский язык слово пришло из ст.-слав.

Answer (score 0):

[Тыц](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8415/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85)